# Updating fields with indirectly related data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have four tables:

- student table with `id_student`, `firstname` and `lastname` fields
- rent table with `id_student` and `id_book`
- book table with `id_book`, `book_name`, `author_name`
- booking table with `id_book`, `current_student`

The rent table only has IDs and links between student and book tables.

How can I update the `booking.current_student` field with a concatenation of `firstname` and `lastname` fields from student table (like 'john doe' ) - for each `id_book` in booking table, update `booking.curent_student` from `student.firstname` and `student.lastname`.

Since the booking table has no `id_student` column, how can I update `booking.current_student` from the student table?

Comment: It would be clearer if you included the DDL for your tables; presumably your student table also has `id_student`? Sample data and expected results would also be helpful. You seem to just want to do an update with the new value as a subquery that joins the other two tables, but it's a bit hard to tell. Why does the title say you want a function? And why do you want to duplicate the name into the booking table anyway, as that may go stale if a student's name changes?

Comment: sorry,yes student table has id_student too. those goals are not in production. dev ask me this for their fonctional test. If i talk about function, this is because i would like to automate this. may be functionis not needed  i'm really lost

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated update, which uses a subquery to get the new value to use in the `set` clause for each row; and that subquery needs to join the rent and student tables:

```
update booking b
set current_student = (
  select s.firstname || ' ' || s.lastname
  from rent r
  join student s on s.id_student = r.id_student
  where r.id_book = b.id_book
);
```

The 'correlation' part is that the subquery filters on `r.id_book = b.id_book`, so it correlates with the outer `booking` (`b`) table which is being updated.

If there are any rows in `booking` which don't have a matching `rent` row then they will be set to null. And if you have multiple `booking` rows for the same `book` ID then they will all be updated to the same student name; and if you have multiple `rent` rows for the same book ID it will error as the subquery will return multiple rows.

It's generally not a good idea to duplicate data like this. It would require less maintenance if you used a view instead:

```
create view booking (id_book, current_name) as
select r.id_book, s.firstname || ' ' || s.lastname
from rent r
join student s on s.id_student = r.id_student;
```

Then as rows are added to or removed from the rent table, or if a student changes their name, the view will automatically reflect the changes without you having to do anything.